# Batch file - file name extract

Tags: batch-file

I can get the jpg file names extracted to a text file using :

```
for  %%a in (*.jpg) do echo %%a >> get_files.txt
```

and this is the output :

Seedling-Acacia-Acinacea-Gold-Dust-Wattle-2-months.jpg

Seedling-Acacia-Acinacea-Gold-Dust-Wattle-6-months.jpg

now I want to output the file name with this path "/images/SeedlingDatabase/"  and the output will be :

/images/SeedlingDatabase/Seedling-Acacia-Acinacea-Gold-Dust-Wattle-2-months.jpg

/images/SeedlingDatabase/Seedling-Acacia-Acinacea-Gold-Dust-Wattle-6-months.jpg

Any help appriciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for full path (*with drive*):

```
for %%a in (*.jpg) do @echo %%~fa
```

for path only (*without file name and drive*):

```
for %%a in (*.jpg) do @echo %%~pa
```

you can also prepend `\images\SeedlingDatabase\` to the variable value making it:

```
for %%a in (*.jpg) do @echo \images\SeedlingDatabase\%%a
```

but i don't think that's exactly what you need

**note**: remove the extra `%` in local for variables when issuing the command directly without putting the code in scripts

Comment: you're welcome. which part exactly suited your need?

Comment: The last part : for %%a in (*.jpg) do @echo \images\SeedlingDatabase\%%a   . Thanks again John