# Getting value from file using Windows Batch scripting

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, batch, extract, findstr

Using Windows Batch scripting, I want to get the **max_volume** value (`-2.9` in the following example) from a ffmpeg output written to a log file:

```
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000000005428b20] n_samples: 13406208

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000000005428b20] mean_volume: -20.4 dB

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000000005428b20] max_volume: -2.9 dB

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000000005428b20] histogram_2db: 7

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000000005428b20] histogram_3db: 181

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000000005428b20] histogram_4db: 963

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000000005428b20] histogram_5db: 2774

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000000005428b20] histogram_6db: 6614

[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000000005428b20] histogram_7db: 14743
```

Once I know that value I intend to use it in some calculations.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Mapg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('find /i "max_volume" ffmpeg.log') do set max_volume=%a

echo %max_volume%
```

it case-insensitively searches the file, determines the line, and then gets its 5th element (`token`) delimited by whitespace by default (absent `delims` option) saving the value in the `max_volume` variable

Comment: +1, but you forgot to double your percents for use in a batch script.

Comment: haha, i thought of it but felt it's getting ugly to repeat it under **ps** on my posts [every](http://superuser.com/questions/822324/batch-file-file-name-extract/822333#822333) [time](http://superuser.com/questions/829390/how-to-project-all-the-files-or-newest-files-that-were-added-to-the-directory-us/829418#829418) i answer about using the batch `for` loop. besides the question wasn't explicitly about executing the batch instructions through script files, and yeah, i think some kind of signature on posts could implement it notifying questioners about common traits, best practices etc :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split the string.

Check this link to see how to do it right:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file